# Nest.JS use AuthGuard as Middleware for GraphQL

Tags: passport.js, graphql, nestjs

I'm trying to make secure my GraphQL endpoint with passportJS in order that every call to this endpoint uses the AuthGuard for validating the token and setting the user on request.user, just as it does in a controller with this code:

```
@Get('findAll')
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('jwt'))
findAll(@Req() request): Promise<Array<Thing>> {
    return this.thingService.findByUser(request.user.email);
}
```

The thing is I want to use it in the graphQL endpoint, which is created like this:

```
consumer
    .apply(graphiqlExpress({ endpointURL: '/graphql' }))
    .forRoutes('/graphiql')
    .apply(
        graphqlExpress(req => ({ schema, rootValue: req })),
        ¿?,
    )
    .forRoutes('/graphql');
```

I suppose I can just set it like a middleware function after the graphqlExpress function, but I have not been successful. Any thoughts?

Thank you in advance!

**Edit**

As a workaround I have implemented the solution proposed on [Nest Docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/guards-interceptors) where it uses the @UseGuard in every query/mutation that must be protected.

However, I want to protect the entire endpoint so that the guard is not called for every protected resolver, but only once on the main request. Is this even possible?

Comment: If you still use modules just like in REST applications in nest you can register the Guard as a provider - see here example for the whole application https://docs.nestjs.com/guards#role-based-authentication . does that solves your problem?

Answer (score 2):

This technically is possible, but it's a pretty sloppy thing to write, and there's absolutely no guarantees it will work with Fastify so heads up. The meat of the functionality comes from the module where you implement the middleware. I ended up doing this all with the `AppModule` which I do not suggest (at least not **all** of the code there), but it works nonetheless.

You need to make the guard a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers) so it can be injected into any context.

Then you need to mock up the `ExecutionContext` using `req, res, next`. This is easier said than done if you want type safety, but if you don't care about that (which I didn't for this) then slap up an `as any` and call it a day.

After that, in the middleware consumer you run the `apply` and make use of `this.guard.canActivate` with that mock `ExecutionContext` you created. Make this middleware `async` and `await` the `canActivate` call. Check that it comes back as `true` and if not then `throw new <ErrorOfYourChoice>()` and boom. It's set up. The code would look (vaguely) like this:

```js
import {
  BadRequestException,
  CanActivate,
  Inject,
  MiddlewareConsumer,
  Module,
  NestModule,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { AppResolver } from './app.resolver';
import { GraphQLModule } from '@nestjs/graphql';
import { JwtModule } from '@nestjs/jwt';
import { AuthGuard, PassportModule } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { JwtStrategy } from './jwt.strategy';

@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      autoSchemaFile: true,
    }),
    JwtModule.register({ secret: 'secret' }),
    PassportModule.register({ defaultStrategy: 'jwt' }),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [
    AppService,
    AppResolver,
    JwtStrategy,
    { provide: 'CustomGuard', useClass: AuthGuard() },
  ],
})
export class AppModule implements NestModule {
  constructor(@Inject('CustomGuard') private readonly guard: CanActivate) {}

  configure(consumer: MiddlewareConsumer) {
    consumer
      .apply(async (req, res, next) => {
        const canActivate = await this.guard.canActivate({
          switchToHttp: () => ({
            getRequest: () => req,
            getResponse: () => res,
            getNext: () => next,
          }),
        } as any);
        if (canActivate) {
          next();
        } else {
          throw new BadRequestException();
        }
      })
      .forRoutes('graphql');
  }
}
```

You can check [this repository](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nestjs-graphql-guard-middleware) for everything wired up and working. Login with `POST /login -d 'username=test1&password=changeme'`, get the JWT and play around with it as you like.

Comment: Hi Jay
The solution doesn't work.
Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: My suggestion is don't use this approach. It's sloppy and hard to manage. Instead, just use guards normally, instead of as middleware

Comment: Me myself like the question am looking for an approach to avoiding using guard on every resolver.

Comment: Then tell me what doesn't work instead of "it doesn't work" because it worked when I made the repo for it

Comment: Decided to take your advice and use the best approach. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

> However, I want to protect the entire endpoint so that the guard is not called for every protected resolver, but only once on the main request. Is this even possible?

I was able to get a middleware function to resolve on every query/mutation by using the reference global approach from NestJS here: https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/field-middleware#global-field-middleware.

Comment: A middleware of that type should run only 1 time per-request, with this approach you are basically calling the same middleware on each fields which is only useful when you need authorization at field-level